# Tables and slicers without interactions

Tags: powerbi

I trying to put three same table on the same canvas. I already put two table with different selection of filters but I can't put last table and also put slicer-filter (identical like previous on the pic). You can see how is look like my canvas :

[image]

At the end I must have have outlook like this pic below:

[image]

So can anybody help e how to solve this problem ?

Comment: So what exactly is your issue? Are your all 3 tables somehow linked/related?? I think you want 3 tables been shown and there respective slicers? Without interacting with each other?

Comment: I want to put same table, three times with same slicers but with different results like last pic.I already put 2 times, but I don't know way for three time Power BI don't allow me put table, values etc

Comment: Might be easy solution, how about you copy your table source to new table as table2 and show that as 3rd table? There might be some better way but this is what I can think of as of now. Does it make sense in your case?

Comment: You can use the visual filter for each of the table or, use the 'Edit Interactions' so the the filter will not affect selected items